# Getting the value from the method is not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to set the value when the state is initialized through the method and depending on the value change the button color. 
The code below is what I have tried. As you see the code, there is a print function and I can print the value which set to true from the REST API which is in *_getState()* method. But I can't set the value to boolean variable called *_selectOn*.

```
class _SecurityScreen extends State<SecurityScreen> {
  static bool _selectOn = setButtonColor();

  void setButtonColor() async {
    _selectOn = await _getState();

    print(_selectOn.toString());
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setButtonColor();
  }
```

The error is

```
The boolean cannot be null.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be

```
class _SecurityScreen extends State<SecurityScreen> {
  bool _selectOn;

  void setButtonColor() async {
    _selectOn = await _getState();

    print(_selectOn.toString());
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setButtonColor();
  }
```